# Object Detection from Webcam Image

Tags: c++, opencv

For a project I am doing, I have a stored "image bank" of several hundred images on my computer. The computer, when its webcam is presented with one of these exact images, needs to be able to determine which of these 100 images it is.

At first, I considered using a histogram to match the images, but I feel that this is not as efficient as it could be, for I know that the presented image will be exactly the same as one of the stored ones (not simply the same object, but also the same image). All I want to be able to do is eliminate all webcam noise, then scale the image's brightness, contrast, etc., and then find the closest match online.

Is there a built-in OpenCV function that does this sort of thing? If not, what sort of algorithm could I write to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of things can be done in opencv by first  extracting recriminative features f form your "bank of images" and represent the features f's in some way to help you with the searching process. To find the features you need to use opencv algorithms SIFT,SURF,FAST or alike. 
To build the searching index since you have only 100 images you can use  KD-tree. If you are going for more image in "bank of images" use the (BoW)Bag of Words representation. All algorithms are included in opencv,its up to your choose and implementations. Hope that give you some info further read the opencv documentation regarding the usage of the algorithms.